# How to assign A block of JavaScript code in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to assign a block or javaScript code into a javascript variable in order to show a block like the following in my Vue template.
[image]

Yet it's ok to add a block of HTML code into a js variable, but when I need to assign HTML/jsx along with javascript, it gives an error. For Example :

```
contextualVariation:
    <template>
        <Badge
            v-for="varient in colors"
            :key="varient.color"
            :color="varient.color"
            :colorName="varient.colorName"
            class="mr-2"
         />
    </template>
```

So far it provides no error. But when I tried :

```
<template>
    <Badge
        v-for="varient in colors"
        :key="varient.color"
        :color="varient.color"
        :colorName="varient.colorName"
        class="mr-2"
    />
</template>

<script>
      . . . . some codes . . . .
</script>
```

Now it gives an error. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**Note: I intented to use this variable in live preview like this:**

```
<live-preview :code=contextualVariation showCode="true" class=""/>
```

Comment: *an error* - just *an* error? or does it give you an error that may indicate the problem in some way other than "an error" ... exactly what do you mean by `javaScript code into a javascript variable` - please show some code if you want help with code

Comment: please elaborate more, it's quite hard to understand the issues. if there's an error please also state the error is about what

Answer (score 0):

if I get it right, you want to render the contextual-variation inside live-preview, something like this:

```
<live-preview> <contextual-variation :colors="colors"></contextual-variation> </live-preview>
```

I don't know why you must pass a Vue component as a prop variable to a another component. Can you provide more info?